# using chromedriver to pull table data from PowerBI based 'leaderboard'

Tags: python, datatable, powerbi, selenium-chromedriver

How can I get the elements in the table?

Trying to locate the elements in a PowerBI table view embedded in a site here:
https://aptera.us/leaderboard/

manually, you have to select each row and use the right-click to 'copy selection'...I want to pull all values from all columns.

I have python with chromedriver running but times out before I find the table or elements.

I'm using this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'.\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://aptera.us/leaderboard/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='navigation-wrapper navigation-wrapper-big']//i[@title='row']"))).click()
print("Country:")
print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='bodyCells']//div[@class='pivotTableCellWrap cell-interactive ']")))[:20]])
driver.quit()
```

this looks to be the element I'm after:

/* @${ID}${name}","extra_options":[]};
/* ]]> */

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: this looks to be the element I'm after?

/* <![CDATA[ */
var BP_Mentions_Options = {"selectors":[".bp-suggestions","#comments form textarea",".wp-editor-area",".bbp-the-content"],"insert_tpl":"@${ID}","display_tpl":"<li data-value=\"@${ID}\"><img src=\"${image}\" \/><span class=\"username\">@${ID}<\/span><small>${name}<\/small><\/li>","extra_options":[]};
/* ]]> */